# Excel VBA Repeatedly Delete Range with Specific String on Top Left

Tags: excel, vba, loops, range

I would like to delete a certain range (3 rows & 19 columns) in excel that contains specific string (*lns*) on the top left of the range, repeatedly. They appear in different rows and columns, but the range size is always the same.
I have written a following code but nothing happens:

```
 For Each vCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
 If InStr(vCell.Value, "*lns*") Then
 Range(Cells(vCell.Row, vCell.Column), Cells(vCell.Row + 2, vCell.Column + 18)).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
 End If
 Next
```

Comment: Please, clarify what "on the top left of the range, repeatedly" should mean. Especially, what "repeatedly" should mean. Please, edit your question and show us such a 'range' and another one after processing. If your problem is only  the `If` statement, `InStr` does not work using wild character. You should try `like`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be faster to locate the cells with `Find`

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub MyMacro()

    Const ROW_SIZE = 3
    Const COL_SIZE = 19
    Const SEARCH = "lns"

    Dim rng As Range, cel As Range
    Dim n As Integer, s As Long
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    Set cel = rng.Find(SEARCH, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlPart, _
                       searchdirection:=xlPrevious)
    Do While Not cel Is Nothing
        cel.Resize(ROW_SIZE, COL_SIZE).Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
        n = n + 1
        Set cel = rng.FindPrevious
        If n > 1000 Then MsgBox "Code Error in Do Loop", vbCritical: Exit Sub
    Loop
    MsgBox n & " blocks deleted", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I does work well and after. I just had to omit the code limiting the iteration up to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Range 'Blocks'

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteBlocks()

    Const rCount As Long = 3
    Const cCount As Long = 19
    Const Criteria As String = "lns"

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Dim fCell As Range
    Set fCell = rg.Find(Criteria, rg.Cells(rg.Rows.Count, rg.Columns.Count), _
        xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows)

    Dim drg As Range ' Delete Range
    Dim brg As Range ' Block Range
    Dim fCount As Long ' Found Count
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    If Not fCell Is Nothing Then
        
        FirstAddress = fCell.Address
        
        Do
            Set brg = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next ' if in last 2 rows or 18 last columns
            Set brg = Intersect(rg, fCell.Resize(rCount, cCount))
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not brg Is Nothing Then
                fCount = fCount + 1
                Set drg = GetCombinedRange(drg, brg)
                Set fCell = rg.FindNext(fCell)
            End If
        Loop Until fCell.Address = FirstAddress
        
        If Not drg Is Nothing Then
            drg.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
        End If
        
        If fCount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "1 block deleted.", vbInformation, "DeleteBlocks"
        Else
            MsgBox fCount & " blocks deleted", vbInformation, "DeleteBlocks"
        End If
    
    Else
        
        MsgBox "No blocks found.", vbExclamation, "DeleteBlocks"
    
    End If
    
End Sub

Function GetCombinedRange( _
    ByVal BuiltRange As Range, _
    ByVal AddRange As Range) _
As Range
    If BuiltRange Is Nothing Then
        Set GetCombinedRange = AddRange
    Else
        Set GetCombinedRange = Union(BuiltRange, AddRange)
    End If
End Function
```